# Doubt on Floating Point Representation

Tags: computer-architecture

$1-2^{-23}$ and $2-2^{-22}$ both represents floating point representation or normalised representation.But are those two represent same value or both have different value? Is floating point representation same as IEEE representation??

Comment: The first is close to 1, the second is close to 2, so they are obviously different. Are those really values you wanted to ask about?

Comment: I mean this  in denormalised number representation it is $(1−2^{−23})×2^{−126}$, and in normalised number it is represented like $(2−2^{−22})×2^{127}$, but I have not got how this comes??

Comment: @Srestha Could you [edit] your question to include this clarification?

Answer (score 2):

> Is floating point representation same as IEEE representation?

Well, not exactly. Floating point is more the abstract idea for "a fractional number" (of arbitrary magnitude) or rather "a number of varying precision.

On the other hand, IEEE(754) is a specific implementation of this idea. Other standards exist and all of them implement "floating point" numbers.

Comment: what is range of max and min floating point number  in normalised and denormalised form?? and how r we getting it?? Is IEEE also have some range??

Comment: IEEE defines the range. Check the standard specification (wiki is a good place to start)